# apt-get Failed to fetch 403 forbidden

Tags: ubuntu

I am trying to use apt-get update on my work computer (running Ubuntu 16.04), and all 3rd party repositories are returning 403 forbidden, even though they work in my browser.

I have tried via the software and updates menu and it says to check my internet connection. Tried different mirrors, apt-get clean, rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* and pinging google.com via terminal works fine. Not sure what else to try. Tried 3 days in a row and always the same.

Here is an output of my apt-get update.

```
Ign:1 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily InRelease
Ign:2 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable InRelease
Ign:3 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable InRelease
Ign:4 http://repository.spotify.com stable InRelease
Ign:5 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release
Ign:6 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable Release
Ign:7 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ InRelease
Ign:8 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release
Ign:9 http://repository.spotify.com stable Release
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:16 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Release
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:27 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Packages.diff/Index
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
Ign:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Hit:40 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial InRelease
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:42 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Packages
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:42 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Packages
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Hit:43 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates InRelease
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Ign:42 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Packages
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Hit:42 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Packages
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Ign:34 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en_AU
Ign:41 http://ubuntu.smp.uq.edu.au ./ Translation-en
Hit:44 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-backports InRelease
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Hit:45 http://au.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-security InRelease
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:12 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign:17 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main all Packages
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Err:11 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:22 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:26 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main Translation-en
Err:10 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main i386 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Err:13 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 Packages
  403  Forbidden
Ign:30 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:14 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 Packages
Ign:18 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free i386 Packages
Ign:35 http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:19 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main all Packages
Ign:21 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free all Packages
Ign:24 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:25 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en_AU
Ign:29 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main Translation-en
Ign:31 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free Translation-en
Ign:33 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:37 http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:15 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main i386 Packages
Ign:20 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main all Packages
Ign:23 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en_AU
Ign:28 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main Translation-en
Ign:32 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:38 http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable/main DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Ign:36 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free amd64 DEP-11 Metadata
Ign:39 http://repository.spotify.com stable/non-free DEP-11 64x64 Icons
Reading package lists...
W: The repository 'http://repository.spotify.com stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu wily Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt stable Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch http://repository.spotify.com/dists/stable/non-free/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://linux.dropbox.com/ubuntu/dists/wily/main/binary-i386/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://dl.google.com/linux/chrome/deb/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Failed to fetch http://desktop-download.mendeley.com/download/apt/dists/stable/main/binary-amd64/Packages  403  Forbidden
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Stack Overflow is for programming questions only, so OS support is [off-topic](/help/on-topic). You can probably ask on [ubuntu.se] instead, but first please take [their tour](//askubuntu.com/tour) and check out [their How to Ask page](//askubuntu.com/help/how-to-ask). (I know this question is old, but I'm saying what I would say to someone who asked it now. On that note, 16.04 is now outdated.)

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

1. run `sudo apt-get install apt-transport-https`
2. Replace http:// with https:// in your /etc/apt/sources.list.d/
3. rerun `sudo apt update`

If that does not work, reinstall the packages manually from deb files provided online.

Comment: Which file in ` /etc/apt/sources.list.d/` ?

Comment: Any, depending on where the line is.